# $\prod_{k=1}^{n - 1} \left(x^2 -2x\cos\left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right) + 1 \right) = 1 + x^2 + ... + x^{2(n-1)}$

Tags: analysis

How do I prove that

$$\prod_{k=1}^{n - 1} \left(x^2 -2x\cos\left(\frac{k \pi}{n}\right) + 1 \right) = 1 + x^2 + ... + x^{2(n-1)}$$

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using induction?

Comment: I think it would be easy to prove that this product is between $x^{2n-2}$ and $x^{2n}$...

Comment: @abiessu no, because there are already two useful suggestions. I see no motivation behind the problem or any attempt to solve this question by the OP.

Comment: @Lost1 you have been on this site too long to ask about brain usage.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The roots of the polynomial on the rights are the square roots of the $n$-th roots of unity. Since the $k$th $n$th root of unity is $\cos 2k\pi/n + i \sin 2k \pi/n,$ its square roots are $\pm( \cos k\pi/n + i \sin k\pi/n).$ Now, group these in conjugate pairs, and you get your LHS.

Comment: Many thanks, Igor, what do you mean conjugate pairs?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz Thanks, fixed!

Comment: @John I mean, since the polynomial has real coefficients, its roots come in complex conjugate pairs (in this case, one such pair is $\cos \pi k/n \pm \sin \pi k/n.$) If you write down the quadratic polynomial with those two numbers as roots, you will get the general term on the LHS.

Comment: Yes, indeed, but how to get the RHS from this general form? Thanks.

Comment: @John Since we showed that the RHS and LHS have the same roots, and they are both monic, they are the same.

Comment: Ah, I see, many thanks! What if I don't know the RHS and start with the LHS, how would I get the RHS? This is a product which arises in quantum field theory.

Comment: @John using the same argument. You have a product of quadratic polynomials. You can solve each one using the quadratic formula, and notice, to your amazement, that they are roots of unity (actually $\pm$ roots of unity, I guess), whereupon the RHS follows.